# How to update an Arch Linux PKGBUILD file for new version (printer driver)?

Tags: arch-linux, aur, makepkg, pkgbuild

I want to install the CUPS driver for the Brother QL-1060N label printer on Arch Linux. Fortunately, there is an AUR package available. (Arch is amazing.)

However, the AUR package is a bit out of date. My question is, how can I edit the PKGBUILD file to install the latest driver version?

[Here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/brother-ql1060n/) is the AUR package. It is for version 1.0.1r0

[Here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=ql1060neus&os=131&dlid=dlfp002233_000&flang=178&type3=591) is the Brother driver download link. The current version is 1.0.5-0.

Below is the PKGBUILD:

```
# Maintainer: Karol Babioch <karol@babioch.de>
# Inspired by package brother-dcp130c

pkgname='brother-ql1060n'
pkgver=1.0.1r0
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc='LPR and CUPS driver for Brother QL-1060N label printer'
url='http://solutions.brother.com/linux/en_us/'
arch=('i686' 'x86_64')
license=('custom')
depends='cups'
if [ "$CARCH" = 'x86_64' ]; then
depends+=('lib32-glibc')
fi
install="$pkgname.install"
source=("http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlfp002231/ql1060nlpr-${pkgver/r/-}.i386.rpm"
        "http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlfp002233/ql1060ncupswrapper-${pkgver/r/-}.i386.rpm"
        'LICENSE')
sha256sums=('f2c2f919ec15b6159e13bfec60bb2d515f8c77a812e349a0ed1ec68ac29f5a25'
            'bf7a1d86234d643547fc9052df55524a5e4ddbd4bf07799988c18666e7d2d3eb'
            'cdd1955a9996bc246ba54e84f0a5ccbfdf6623962b668188762389aa79ef9811')

prepare()
{
#  do not install in '/usr/local'
if [ -d $srcdir/usr/local/Brother ]; then
    install -d $srcdir/usr/share
    mv $srcdir/usr/local/Brother/ $srcdir/usr/share/brother
    rm -rf $srcdir/usr/local
    sed -i 's|/usr/local/Brother|/usr/share/brother|g' `grep -lr '/usr/local/Brother' ./`
fi

# setup cups directories
install -d "$srcdir/usr/share/cups/model"
install -d "$srcdir/usr/lib/cups/filter"

#  go to the cupswrapper directory and find the source file from wich to generate a ppd- and wrapper-file
cd `find . -type d -name 'cupswrapper'`
if [ -f cupswrapper* ]; then
    _wrapper_source=`ls cupswrapper*`
    sed -i '/^\/etc\/init.d\/cups/d' $_wrapper_source
    sed -i '/^sleep/d' $_wrapper_source
    sed -i '/^echo lpadmin/d' $_wrapper_source
    sed -i '/^lpadmin/d' $_wrapper_source
    sed -i 's|/usr|$srcdir/usr|g' $_wrapper_source
    sed -i 's|/opt|$srcdir/opt|g' $_wrapper_source
    sed -i 's|/model/Brother|/model|g' $_wrapper_source
    sed -i 's|lpinfo|echo|g' $_wrapper_source
    export srcdir=$srcdir
    ./$_wrapper_source
    sed -i 's|$srcdir||' $srcdir/usr/lib/cups/filter/*lpdwrapper*
    sed -i "s|$srcdir||" $srcdir/usr/lib/cups/filter/*lpdwrapper*
    rm $_wrapper_source
fi

#  /etc/printcap is managed by cups
rm `find $srcdir -type f -name 'setupPrintcap*'`
}

package() {
cd "$srcdir"

cp -R usr $pkgdir
if [ -d opt ]; then cp -R opt $pkgdir; fi

install -Dm0644 LICENSE "$pkgdir/usr/share/licenses/$pkgname/LICENSE"
}
```

The .install file in the package archive include only this:

```
post_install() {
post_upgrade;
}

post_upgrade() {
echo "Restart CUPS to load the new files"
echo "You can now register your new printer using the web interface at:"
echo "  http://localhost:631/"
}
```

Some questions include:

Why isn't [rpmextract](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/rpmextract/) required in the PKGBUILD code? I don't understand how the install is working given that the packages are RPMs and this is Arch.

Regarding the sha256sums, I assume I just manually download the rpm files and calculate those sums given that the Brother download page doesn't list them (afaik).

The values I come up with are:

```
05d786b9a5b2cf374d5c286ae8feb77e2a79619cc5b2f6ca2695dbd549eec0a3  ql1060ncupswrapper-1.0.5-0.i386.rpm
bf20a00f723d0e12cf055ae359d0e03e2c1bd839bacd52f02b3cc5a63bc652e5  ql1060nlpr-1.0.5-0.i386.rpm
```

I assume the license file and it's sha256sum can remain unchanged.

Given that, is updating the PKGBUILD as simple as replacing the sha256sums and updating this one value?

```
pkgver=1.0.1r0
```

with

```
pkgver=1.0.5-0
```

## UPDATE

The package maintainer has updated the package already. Here is a diff:

```
5c5
< pkgver=1.0.1r0
---
> pkgver=1.0.5r0
19,20c19,20
< sha256sums=('f2c2f919ec15b6159e13bfec60bb2d515f8c77a812e349a0ed1ec68ac29f5a25'
<             'bf7a1d86234d643547fc9052df55524a5e4ddbd4bf07799988c18666e7d2d3eb'
---
> sha256sums=('bf20a00f723d0e12cf055ae359d0e03e2c1bd839bacd52f02b3cc5a63bc652e5'
>             '05d786b9a5b2cf374d5c286ae8feb77e2a79619cc5b2f6ca2695dbd549eec0a3'
```

However, I'll leave the question up because I would like to understand how this PKGBUILD works and how an RPM package can be installed using this method.

Comment: Regarding your last question yes, since its basically a downloader for the RPM. However the package build is making assumptions about the file structure contained in the RPM. So if that changed it may no longer work.